# Unhide a Game Object when triggered an another game object

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

so i have 2 game objects . the first game object is setActive(false); and the second game object is the one when i triggered, the first game object must setActive(true); but i cant seem to do it .. im just a beginner in Unity

```
#pragma strict
function Start () 
{
    GameObject.Find("jumpImage").SetActive(false);
}

function OnTriggerEnter(col:Collider)
{   
    if(col.tag=="Player")
    {
        GameObject.Find("jumpImage").SetActive(true);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GameObject.Find only finds "ACTIVE" game objects which you can see in the documentation for [GameObject.Find](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html).

With that said, if you're referencing the same GameObject between Start and the OnTriggerEnter functions, you might as well store a reference after you first find it.

```
#pragma strict

var jumpImageGO : GameObject;

function Start () 
{
    jumpImageGO = GameObject.Find("jumpImage");
    if (jumpImageGO != null)
        jumpImageGO.SetActive(false);
}

function OnTriggerEnter(col:Collider)
{
    if(col.tag=="Player")
    {
        jumpImageGO.SetActive(true);
    }       
}
```

Comment: sir . can i add a delay when i want to set it active ??

Comment: Sure, just use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html) and set a delay or use [WaitForSeconds](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WaitForSeconds.html).